# Can TensorFlow save the variables in a certain variable_scope?

Tags: tensorflow

I know that TensoFlow can save the certain variables by explicitly specifying the variable list as follow:

```
var1 = tf.get_variable('var_1', shape, dtype)
var2 = tf.get_variable('var_2', shape, dtype)
saver = tf.train.Saver([var1, var2])
saver.save(sess, path)
```

But i don not whether TF could **save the variables in a certain variable_scope** or not because if i want to pre-train a model and the parameters are all in a certain variable_scope, it will be convenient to save all the variables in the variable_scope and restore it.
If TF are not able to realize the function now, please give me some advises on how to pre-train models and saving the parameters of the pre-trained model.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) for a  variable scope with prefix `scope_prefix` using [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection) as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(
    tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope_prefix))
```